# Vim folding: how to map <space> to recursively open/close?

Tags: vim

In vim, it is often recommended to map `<space>` key in normal mode to `za` -- toggle current fold open/close. But I personally find this not enough. In particular, I'd like to map `<space>` to recursively open/close current fold, i.e.

```
If currently folded, map <space> to zO
If currently unfolded, map <space> to zC
```

How can I achieve that in my `.vimrc`?

Comment: isn't `zA` sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want! I didn't know about it. Thanks!

Comment: ok, then I put it as an answer. Just want to make sure first what are you looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zA` is same as `za`, just toggle fold recursively depending on the current fold. It should fit your requirement.